# Excel: Match and Index based on range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stumped with the following problem and not sure how to accomplish it in excel. Here is an example of the data:

```
    A            B
 1 Date        Stock_Return
 2 Jan-95     -5.2%
 3 Feb-95     2.1%
 4 Mar-95     3.7%
 5 Apr-95     6.9%
 6 May-95     6.5%
 7 Jun-95    -5.6%
 8 Jul-95     6.6%
 9 Aug-95     6.2%
```

What I would like is to have the dates returned which fall within a certain return range and sorted from low to high.

For example:

```
                    1        2       3      4      5 
   Below -7%        0        0       0      0      0 
  -7% to -5%        Jun-95   Jan-95  0      0      0
  -5% to -3%        0        0       0      0      0
  -3% to 0%         0        0       0      0      0
  0% to 3%          Feb-95   0       0      0      0
  3% to 5%          Mar-95   0       0      0      0
  5% to 7%          Aug-95   May-95  Jul-95 Apr-95 0
```

I thought Index and Match might make the most sense but when I drag across columns it doesn't work. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: PivotTable? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576#OfficeVersion=Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$9/(($B$2:$B$9>$D2)*($B$2:$B$9<=$E2)),COLUMN(A1)),"0")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! That is very helpful. Is there anyway to organize the data so that it is from low to high. Using the range -7% to -5% have 01.95 then 06.95?

Comment: Yes, change first argument of ```AGGREGATE``` function to 15

Comment: sorry I worded my question badly. Is there any way to order based on the values in column B i.e. low to high?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365, you can use the `FILTER` function:

```
F2: =IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$2:$A$9,(F2<=$B$2:$B$9)*(G2>=$B$2:$B$9))),"")
```

and fill down.

[image]